# Find which values are in every group in pandas

Tags: pandas

Is there a way of aggregating or transforming in pandas that would give me the list of values that are present in each group.

For example, taking this data

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | module_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         A |
|       1 |         B |
|       1 |         C |
|       2 |         A |
|       2 |         B |
|       2 |         D |
|       3 |         B |
|       3 |         C |
|       3 |         D |
|       3 |         E |
+---------+-----------+
```

how would I complete this code

```
df.groupby('user_id')
```

to give the result C, the only module_id that is in each of the groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max` for indicator `DataFrame` and then filter only `1` columns - `1` values are processes like `True`s in [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```python
cols = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('user_id')['module_id'])
          .max(level=0)
          .loc[:, lambda x: x.all()].columns)
print (cols)
Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

Similar solution:

```python
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('user_id')['module_id']).max(level=0)
print (df1)
```

```
         A  B  C  D  E
user_id               
1        1  1  1  0  0
2        1  1  0  1  0
3        0  1  1  1  1
```

```python
cols = df1.columns[df1.all()]
```

More solutions:

```python
cols = df.groupby(['module_id', 'user_id']).size().unstack().dropna().index
print (cols)
Index(['B'], dtype='object', name='module_id')
```

---

```python
cols = df.pivot_table(index='module_id', columns='user_id', aggfunc='size').dropna().index
```